# Looping through pandas data frame and creating new column value

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to loop through a csv file which I converted into a pandas data frame.

I need to loop through each line and check the latitude and longitude data I have (2 separate columns) and append a code (0,1 or 2) to the the same line depending on whether the lat, long data falls within a certain range.

I'm somewhat new to python and would love any help ya'll might have.

It's throwing off quite a few errors at me.

```
book = 'yellow_tripdata_2014-04.csv'
write_book = 'yellow_04.csv'
yank_max_long = -73.921630300
yank_min_long = -73.931169700 
yank_max_lat = 40.832823000
yank_min_lat = 40.825582000
mets_max_long = 40.760523000
mets_min_long = 40.753277000
mets_max_lat = -73.841035400   
mets_min_lat = -73.850564600   

df = pd.read_csv(book)


##To check for Yankee Stadium Lat's and Long's, if within gps units then Stadium_Code = 1 , if mets then Stadium_Code=2

df['Stadium_Code'] = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if yank_min_lat <= float(row['dropoff_latitude']) <= yank_max_lat and yank_min_long <=float(row('dropoff_longitude')) <=yank_max_long:
        row['Stadium_Code'] == 1
    elif mets_min_lat <= float(row['dropoff_latitude']) <= mets_max_lat and mets_min_long <=float(row('dropoff_longitude')) <=mets_max_long:
        row['Stadium_Code'] == 2
```

I tried using the .loc command but ran into this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-9a9166772646> in <module>()
----> 1 yank_mask = (df['dropoff_latitude'] > yank_min_lat) & (df['dropoff_latitude'] <= yank_max_lat) & (df['dropoff_longitude'] > yank_min_long) & (df['dropoff_longitude'] <= yank_max_long)
      2 
      3 mets_mask = (df['dropoff_latitude'] > mets_min_lat) & (df['dropoff_latitude'] <= mets_max_lat) & (df['dropoff_longitude'] > mets_min_long) & (df['dropoff_longitude'] <= mets_max_long)
      4 
      5 df.loc[yank_mask, 'Stadium_Code'] = 1

/Users/benjaminprice/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1795             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1796         else:
-> 1797             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1798 
   1799     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/Users/benjaminprice/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   1802         # get column
   1803         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 1804             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   1805 
   1806         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionaility

/Users/benjaminprice/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1082         res = cache.get(item)
   1083         if res is None:
-> 1084             values = self._data.get(item)
   1085             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1086             cache[item] = res

/Users/benjaminprice/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   2849 
   2850             if not isnull(item):
-> 2851                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   2852             else:
   2853                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/Users/benjaminprice/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py in get_loc(self, key, method)
   1570         """
   1571         if method is None:
-> 1572             return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
   1573 
   1574         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3824)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12280)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12231)()

KeyError: 'dropoff_latitude'
```

I'm usually not too bad at figuring out what these error codes mean, but this one threw me off.

Comment: Generally when you report that you're getting errors it's useful to post the error traces and the lines they occur on.

Comment: Your error means you've misnamed your columns, can you post the output from `df.columns.tolist()`

Comment: ['vendor_id',
 ' pickup_datetime',
 ' dropoff_datetime',
 ' passenger_count',
 ' trip_distance',
 ' pickup_longitude',
 ' pickup_latitude',
 ' rate_code',
 ' store_and_fwd_flag',
 ' dropoff_longitude',
 ' dropoff_latitude',
 ' payment_type',
 ' fare_amount',
 ' surcharge',
 ' mta_tax',
 ' tip_amount',
 ' tolls_amount',
 ' total_amount',
 'Stadium_Code']

Comment: ahhhh.... I think there's an opening space in the columns

Comment: then you need to either fix the names or pass the name that your columns actually are, when you see a `KeyError` it usually means that there is no match for the column name passed through

Comment: Thanks a ton! I just added a space and everything worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it's pretty wasteful to iterate row-wise when there are vectorised solutions available that will operate on the whole df at once.

I'd create a boolean mask of your 2 conditions and pass these to `.loc` to mask the rows that meet the criteria and set these to the values.

Here the masks use the bitwise operators `&` to `and` the conditions and parentheses are used around each condition due to operator precedence.

So the following should work:

```
yank_mask = (df['dropoff_latitude'] > yank_min_lat) & (df['dropoff_latitude'] <= yank_max_lat) & (df['dropoff_longitude'] > yank_min_long) & (df['dropoff_longitude'] <= yank_max_long)

mets_mask = (df['dropoff_latitude'] > mets_min_lat) & (df['dropoff_latitude'] <= mets_max_lat) & (df['dropoff_longitude'] > mets_min_long) & (df['dropoff_longitude'] <= mets_max_long)

df.loc[yank_mask, 'Stadium_Code'] = 1
df.loc[mets_mask, 'Stadium_Code'] = 2
```

If not already done so I'd read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) as will aid you in understanding how the above works

Comment: I tried this method before but tried a way I was more familiar with after encountering the errors above (recently edited the post).